# Boolean matrix multiplication in Julia

Tags: boolean, julia, matrix-multiplication

I need to multiply two boolean matrices in Julia.

Doing simply `A*A` or `A^2` returns an Int64 Matrix.

Is there a way how to multiply efficiently boolean matrices?

Comment: Do you want element wise multiplication? Matrix multiplication of boolean matrices should return a matrix of `Int`.

Comment: I need Boolean matrix multiplication as described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_matrix . 
I.e. `AB[i,j] = any([A[i,k] & B[k,j] for k in 1:N])` where N is the size of the index that is multiplied.

Comment: Julia doesn't have an inbuilt function for this (It's not that standard). That said, you could basically put 2 for loops around what you just wrote, and you would get an efficient method. (especially if you used `LoopVectorization` for the loops).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One very simple solution is

```
function bool_mul(A,B)
    return A*B .!= 0
end
```

This won't be the most efficient since it will allocate a matrix for `A*B`, but might end up being one of the fastest solutions available.

Comment: I guess this might be indeed the best solution concerning time for sparse matrices. For space issues it might be more convenient to use the nested loops using `any`, which is anyways more convenient for dense matrices.

Answer (score 8):

Following Oscar's comment of adding two `for` loops around your code, but without the LoopVectorization improvement, although with not allocating the full array inside the `any` call (so that the `any` stops on the first occurrence), this is decently fast (edit: replaced standard AND `&` with short-circuit `&&`):

```
function bool_mul2(A, B)
    mA, nA = size(A)
    mB, nB = size(B)
    nA ≠ mB && error()
    AB = BitArray(undef, mA, nB)
    for i in 1:mA, j in 1:nB
        AB[i,j] = any(A[i,k] && B[k,j] for k in 1:nA)
    end
    AB
end
```

(Note I removed the `[` and `]` inside the `any` to not allocate there.

E.g., with `A` and `B` of size 1000×1000, I get

```
julia> @btime bool_mul2($A, $B) ;
  16.128 ms (3 allocations: 122.25 KiB)
```

compared to

```
julia> @btime bool_mul($A, $B) ;
  346.374 ms (12 allocations: 7.75 MiB)
```

---

EDIT: For squaring the matrix, maybe try

```
function bool_square(A)
    m, n = size(A)
    m ≠ n && error()
    A² = BitArray(undef, n, n)
    for i in 1:n, j in 1:n
        A²[i,j] = any(A[i,k] && A[k,j] for k in 1:n)
    end
    A²
end
```

for which I get

```
julia> A = rand(Bool, 500, 500) ;

julia> @btime $A * $A .!= 0 ;
  42.483 ms (12 allocations: 1.94 MiB)

julia> @btime bool_square($A) ;
  4.653 ms (3 allocations: 30.69 KiB)
```

Comment: Assuming the matrices are `rand(Bool, 1000, 1000)`, I think you'll have to wait longer than the age of the universe to get an answer which isn't `trues(1000, 1000)`. Although even at size 10x10, stopping early with `any` (after 3 steps on average, I believe) seems faster than full loops with `@avx`.

Comment: I need to multiply sparse matrices efficiently because I want to implement [Seidel's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seidel%27s_algorithm) to calculate the APSP for unweighted undirected sparse graphs to improve on the existing `LightGraphs.jl` algorithms. To square sparse adjacency matrices of size 500x500 it actually takes ~700ms, which is by far slower than Integer multiplication (50ms).

Comment: Well if it is sparse I think `A * A .≠ 0` will be faster then.